# How to pass date from date picker on button press (ng-bootstrap | Angular 2)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using the ngbDatepicker for Angular 2 and would like to pass the selected date to my getData() method, were I simply alert(date). I am unable to reverse engineer the sample code and make this work.

Plunker Sample Code: Press the down arrow on the toolbar next to 'Datepicker in a popup.' for the original sample code from ng-bootstrap team.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

In my component I have added one method, and I would like to put the selected date into it.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})

export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {

  model;

  getData() {
    alert('How do I get the selected date here?');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking from the docs and the plunker, you don't need to pass anything. When you two-way bind the model in your template

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model"></ngb-datepicker>
```

the datepicker will automatically update the model in your component. That's how `[(ngModel)]` works. So when you click, just get the data from the model

```
model: NgbDateStruct;

getData() {
  alert(`${this.model.day}-${this.model.month}-${this.model.year}`);
}
```

Comment: I see, because it's a NgbDateStruct. Is there a one way binding from the Dom to the Class, save using a two way binding here?

Comment: @Paul Samsotha Where is the button that triggers the getData() function? I think you still need a button to trigger this function.